# How to set a window controllers Appearance and title in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, cocoa, visual-studio-2012

I have recently downloaded Visual Studio for Mac and have created a new Cocoa Project as shown below.

[image: Creating Project]

I have found the storyboard file that I am able to use inside this project to create the UI and have started doing so. On the internet I found that you are able to set the appearance and the titleVisibilty of a window controller inside Xcode so that it looks like this:

[image: Example of what I am aiming for]

The problem I'm having is I have no idea where to put the two lines of code that actually change these features of the window controller as I have never used this type of project before. I am hoping someone is able to tell me which file I should implement these changes in and how to write the code that is needed?

Thank You.

Comment: *On the internet I found that you are able to set the appearance and the title Visibilty of a window controller* - what is the link? what are the two lines of code? any other research you have done, this seems quite trivial.

Comment: Sorry. Here is the link a video showing someone do this in an Xcode project: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JHmAXqpST44. And the lines of codes he use he puts in the window controller.swift file which he connects to the window controller in the storyboard, the code is:    window?.titleVisibility = .hidden.  and window?.appearance = NSAppearance(named: NSAppearanceNameVibrantDark)

Comment: I am basically unsure how to replicate this in the project type I talked about above and which file it needs to go into to?

Comment: I don't think Xamarin supports this directly yet. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419635-titlevisibility is the Cocoa documentation and I don't see this property in Xamarin documentation https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoMac.AppKit.NSWindow/

Comment: Thank you LucasDerraugh for confirming that!!